# What should be an MVC route for this URL?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I need to define an MVC route for URL like this:

```
http://localhost/RealSuiteApps/RealHelp/-1/Detail/BRK18482020
```

where:

Detail - is controller name

- default action Index should be executed
- -1 is some client id
- BRK18482020 is **orderId**

**I need this to go to DetailController, Index action with orderId parameter.**

I tried this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Detail",
    url: "Detail/{id}",
    defaults: new { clientid = "-1", controller = "Detail", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

but I get a message "Page Not Found". **What am I missing here ??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming DetailController action

```
public ActionResult Index(int clientId, string orderId) { ... }
```

Then route would be mapped as

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Detail",
    url: "{cientId}/Detail/{orderId}",
    defaults: new { clientid = "-1", controller = "Detail", action = "Index" }
);
```

Note that this should also be registered before any default routes.